How to read LoadRunner Analysis results with Java
In our project, we're currently using LoadRunner Analysis to obtain performance test results. However, we now need to develop a Java program to read these test results and store them in a database. What's the best approach to achieve this?
I'm using LoadRunner 12.0 and the generated OUTPUT.MDB file is in an Access database format. I've tried using Java to open the file, but I'm unable to extract the data I need in a usable format. Is there a way to directly query the database or extract the data into a CSV file using a scripting language like Java?

You can use a third-party JDBC driver "UCanAccess" to interact with the Access file or MicroSoft Access to manually export the .mdb tables into CSV format and then use Java to process the data.

Yes, I tried using a third-party JDBC driver to read the Access file, but I don’t know how to correlate the tables and data inside with the test results. What I need is data similar to the result report displayed on Analysis.

What do you mean by correlating the tables and data inside the test results?

Emmm, my idea is to obtain the chart data content displayed on LoadRunner Analysis.

As I said, for the data that you want to read and store in the database, you use any method I suggested to read and then use Java to process them and save them in the database using FileWriter.

Okay, I will give it a try.

The scheme is stored in the META table, describing the relationships between the tables.
If you are only interested in a timing record report, such as you would get out of Jmeter, then just use Jmeter.
Analysis is where the value is added in any performance testing effort, where results ar converted to findings, and findings to actionable items to change to improve performance.  if you have no interest in analysis (nor value), just use a tool that doesn't have it.

Charts are not stored in the database, only raw metrics.  You can, however, define a template containing the charts and the tables you want and have that processed at the end of every single test for output in a variety of formats, HTML, Word, and PDF included

Excel too.
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/24.1-24.3/help/WebHelp/Content/Analysis/102150_ui_template_dialog.htm

Okay, I will give it a try.

Why don't you just automate what you need with analysis?
You can store the results in a Microsoft SQL Server database instead of MS Access if you wish.
If your desire is to compare one test to another, that feature is built into analysis.
If you are looking for long term trending on requests then it becomes easier to get that out of logs with the HTTP logs with time-taken enabled, or using RUM with JavaScript inside of functional testing

Yes, now I want to use the LoadRunner Analysis API to automatically read .lrr files and generate the data I need. I wonder if it is possible to connect to the relevant interfaces using Java?

This is a .Net interface.   So the odds close on zero using Java to do this.   You can export results and graphs to an excel formatted document using a template or manually.  Takes all of five minutes to setup
